# How to check the null values in Telerik grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I want to check the null values in   Telerik grid.
Because I want to show the first 10 characters.

```
if "Address" is null it getting an error and it says
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

This is my code.

```
     @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
                      .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.PKID).Title("ID");

            columns.Bound(o => o.PKID)
.Width(50)
   .Template(o => o.Address.Substring(0, 10)+ "...").Title("TO");// Eroor is hers      
        })
          .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(15).Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric).Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom))
                 .Sortable()
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

First, Telerik (or Kendo) `Grid` doesn't support well a nested properties. It's better to avoid such properties in a model.

Second, you need to check for non null value and address length in a `Template` method call:

```
.Template(o => o.Address != null && o.Address.Length > 10 ? 
    o.Address.Substring(0, 10) + "..." : o.Address).Title("TO")
```